# Controller returns a null IActionResult when running xUnit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

I'm having some difficulties making my unit test pass.

This is my unit test class:

```
[Collection(nameof(VehicleControllerCollection))]
public class DetectVin
{
    private readonly VehicleControllerFixture _controllerFixture;

    public DetectVin(VehicleControllerFixture controllerFixture)
    {
        _controllerFixture = controllerFixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ReturnsBadRequestGivenPictureIsNull()
    {
        var controllerMock = _controllerFixture.VehicleController;
        controllerMock.Protected().Setup<bool>("HasAnyLicenseClaims", ItExpr.IsAny<string[]>()).Returns(true);
        var result = await controllerMock.Object.DetectVin(null, 1) as BadRequestResult;

        result.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

It is using a `CollectionFixture` that looks like this:

```
public class VehicleControllerFixture
{
    public Mock<v1.v1._0.Vehicle.VehicleController> VehicleController { get; set; }

    public VehicleControllerFixture()
    {
        var vehicleServiceMock = new Mock<IVehicleService>();
        VehicleController = new Mock<v1.v1._0.Vehicle.VehicleController>(vehicleServiceMock.Object);
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition(nameof(VehicleControllerCollection))]
public class VehicleControllerCollection : ICollectionFixture<VehicleControllerFixture>
{
}
```

And the method that's being test `DetectVin` looks like this:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(5242880)]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DetectVin([FromBody]string picture, [FromQuery]int activityId)
{
    if (!HasAnyLicenseClaims("ModuleMyWorkshopHGSService", "ModuleMyWorkshopToyotaService")) { return NotAllowed(); }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(picture))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var result = await _vehicleService.DetectVin(picture);
        
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
    {
        return UnprocessableEntity();
    }

    var activityVinDetection = new ActivityVinDetection
    {
        ActivityId = activityId,
        UsedOnActivity = false,
        Vin = result
    };

    _vehicleService.InsertActivityVinDetection(activityVinDetection);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

My problem is that the `DetectVin` method always returns `null`. This is even though I can debug the test and step through the method just fine, seeing that it actually returns the `BadRequest()`.

Anyone has any idea why that could be?

EDIT:

Here is the base controller that the `VehicleController` inherits from:

```
public abstract class AIdpClaimsAuthController : BaseController, IAuthorizedController
{
    public int WorkshopId
    {
        get
        {
            var wid = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(sd => sd.Type == "sub");
            if (wid == null || !int.TryParse(wid.Value, out int workshopId))
            {
                throw new System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException("Unauthorized");
            }
            return workshopId;
        }
    }
        
    protected virtual bool HasAnyLicenseClaims(params string[] licenseClaims)
    {
        foreach (var claim in licenseClaims)
        {
            if (AuthorizationService.HasLicenseClaims(WorkshopId, claim))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the base controller that the `AIdpClaimsAuthController` inherits from:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private IAuthorizationService __authorizationService;
    public IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
    {
        get
        {
            if (__authorizationService == null)
            {
                __authorizationService = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAuthorizationService)) as IAuthorizationService;
            }
            return __authorizationService;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would first like to understand why the subject under test is being mocked as well? `DetectVin` returns null in the test because the "mocked" controller was not setup to do anything when that member is invoked. I believe this post is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you're trying to test a method of the controller class, then you shouldn't be operating on a mock of the controller class. You should be operating on the actual controller class.

Comment: @Nkosi - The reason why I'm mocking the sut is because I need to mock the result of the method HasAnyLicenseClaims which is a protected method on the base class inherited by the controller that I'm testing. It makes sense that it returns null when I'm operating on a mock. But why can I debug the method then?

Comment: @NicholasMagnussen You mean debug the method during the test or normal run time debug?

Comment: @Nkosi - During the test.

Comment: I find it strange that it even hits the actual method even though `CallBase` was not set

Comment: remove the cast to a separate line and see for sure during debug that the action method actually returns null

Comment: @Nkosi - I've done that and sadly, it's still null

Comment: Show the `HasAnyLicenseClaims`. there has to be some way to arrange the controller so that you don't have to mock it as the subject under test. It is because you are mocking the controller that you are encountering a problem.

Comment: @Nkosi - Added the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using `MockBehaviour.Strict`.
Turns out that I also needed to mock the result that my controller generated for the `BadRequest` method.